# MaridaDB Error and Wont Start

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

I am unable to get MariaDB to start. `systemctl status mariadb.service` gives me this following:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.25 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-11-01 17:59:48 EST; 9s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 1281 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1282 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1284 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && syst
  Process: 1331 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1331 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 01 17:59:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.25 database server...
Nov 01 17:59:45 raspberrypi mysqld[1331]: 2020-11-01 17:59:45 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 1331 ...
Nov 01 17:59:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 01 17:59:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 17:59:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.25 database server.
```

My mysql Error Log says:

```
2020-11-01 19:26:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-11-01 19:26:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-11-01 19:26:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-01 19:26:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=77688449
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace 54 was not found at ./raspberrypints/log.ibd.
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore this and to permanently lose all changes to the tablespace.
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Tablespace not found
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-11-01 19:26:51 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It seems like it's looking for log.ibd in raspberrypints but that file is not there. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Was that file moved or removed? BTW, your journalctl output is truncated.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is probably a restore from backup job.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a database corruption occurred with data stored in InnoDB engine. It could be that you still can recover from it, there are a lot of guides available on the network: [example 1](https://blackbird.si/mysql-corrupted-innodb-tables-recovery-step-by-step-guide/), [example 2](https://iserversupport.com/recover-crashed-innodb-tables-on-mysql-database-server/).